# Question regarding use of low voltage high current outputs

Tags: transformer, high-current

I see every day high voltage, high current; high voltage, low current. I rarely see low voltage, high current; why?

I know that I can take a high voltage, high current signal, send it through a step-down transformer and theoretically get a low voltage high current (with the same power output, of course), but I never see this done.

Can someone give me a reason as to why I wouldn't want a low-voltage high-current scenario?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a perfect example of a low voltage, high current device: a **welder**. Voltage as low as a few tens of volts, currents over 100A. That's kiloWatts.
The reason you don't see the combination low voltage/high current that often is that it's a rather inefficient way to get the power required: you need thick cables to carry the high current. It's much more practical to run the 1.5kW water kettle on 230V AC, so that it only needs 6.5A, than to run it on 20V, where you would need a thick cable to carry the 75A. Remember that we get the high voltage of 230V/115V from the grid already.

Comment: Another example for high current at low voltage are desktop CPUs, at say 1V and 100A. Though this is converted down from higher voltages by converters very close to the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Can you followup with this question? : Why do I need to convert my 230V or 120V to a lower voltage, if the device is just going to pull the current required to reach its desired Power? i.e. I can't use an 18v DC power supply to power a 5V DC device

Comment: @IDLacrosseplayer - Power consumption. If the load is resistive, say 1k\$\Omega\$, at 5V it will consume 25mW, at 18V this would be 324mW, or 13 times as much. Even with a fixed current load the 5V device will consume 72% less than the 18V device. In the kettle case you *want* high power consumption, the same kettle at 5V will never bring the water to cooking temperatures.

Answer (score 11):

First, it may help to think of voltage as pressure and current as flow.  Various combinations of high/low voltage/current are used.  For example, low voltage and high current is used to run the starter motor in your car.  It's only 12V, but can exceed 100A.  However note the drawback, which is thick cables going to the starter.

From a pure power standpoint any product of voltage and current that results in the same value is equivalent.  However, losses in real systems can be proportional to current, especially when the electric power has to be moved some distance.

Let's say you had to deliver 1kW 100m away.  In theory, 10A at 100V and 100A at 10V are equivalent.  However, back in reality we're stuck with real cable, not theoretical ones.  The voltage a cable has to be able to handle effects how it is insulated.  The current a cable has to be able to handle effects how thick the conductor is.  Insulating to 100V is trivial.  Just about any layer of insulation you put on the cable will do 100V.  You wouldn't save any money trying to make a cable only good for withstanding 10V.  Just to overcome external mechanical stresses and normal abrasion, the insulation will be thick enough to withstand 100V without much additional cost.  However, the thicker conductor costs real money.  Copper or whatever you use as the conductor will have a significant cost to carry 100A for 100m.  Now consider that the power lost in the cable (a resistor for this purpose) is proportional to the *square* of the current thru it.  To get the same total power loss in the cable at 100A as you did at 10A, you actually need *100 times* as much conductor material.

Now think about transferring 100s of MW between power generating stations and cities.  The economics favor making the voltage as high as possible and thereby decreasing the current for the same level of power.  Such transmission lines usually work in the 500kV to 1MV range.  There are costs at really high voltages too.  Power companies carefully study the tradeoffs in deciding what voltage to run a transmission line at.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, what exactly do you think is wrong?

Answer (score -5):

I always like to give the water and plumbing analogy here.

If you think of the voltage as the diameter of a pipe, and the current as force of the pump moving the water.  The water coming out of the end of the pipe, say in gallons per minute, is the power.

Now, if you increase the diameter of the pipe (the voltage), you can get more water through at once - thus increasing the "power".

Also, if you increase the force of the pump (the current), you force the water through faster.  This however increases the pressure inside the pipe, so you need to use a pipe with a thicker wall.  This is equivalent to the size of the conductor.  Bigger conductors (or thicker walled pipes) can hold more current without "bursting" (melting).

Of course, making the pipe too big (too high a voltage) and the eco-protestors all turn up and start complaining about the damage laying the pipe does to the countryside, and people start to get hurt (electrocution), so you need to build bigger and better barriers to keep people away (insulation).

So, you can see that there is always a balancing act between the thickness of the pipe wall and the diameter of the pipe in order to get the amount of water through it that you need.

Yes, I know the analogy isn't quite 100% right, but it's good for getting an understanding of the relationships between them.

Comment: Your plumbing analogy in the second paragraph is completely wrong.  The diameter of the pipe is more analagous to the inverse of resistance, *voltage* is the force moving the water, and gallons/minute is analagous to *current* not power.  The remaining errors in this post seem to follow from your original basic misconceptions.

Comment: Like I said, it's not 100% right, and you may equate them to something different to me.  This is how ***I*** equate them.  Regardless of what you equate them to, this helps me to teach other people successfully about how the different values interact.

Comment: The water analogy can be useful, but I'm sorry, you just have it wrong.  Voltage is pressure, current is flow, power is pressure times flow, just like it's voltage times current in electronics.  That's how the physics works.  You can't just make up what you want and still stick to the physics.

Comment: It all depends on your point of view.  Like any analogy there is *no right and no wrong* way of looking at it.  In this case it depends on if you're focussing on the water speed or the water quantity.  The two create completely different analogies, neither of which is right, and neither is wrong.  I suggest you read up on what an analogy is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogy

Comment: "Other much weaker analogies assist in understanding and describing functional behaviours of similar systems. For instance, an analogy commonly used in electronics textbooks compares electrical circuits to hydraulics." - I think your analogy is more akin to hydraulics and not plumbing.  Just because mine is not the same as yours does not immediately mean that it is wrong.  Sometimes, Olin, your answer is not the only right one.  There are sometimes others.#

Comment: No, this one doesn't depend on point of view or opinion.  Even if your analogy could somehow be viewed as not incorrect, it would still be very very misleading at best, and do a lot of harm in using it to try to teach someone about electricity.

Comment: I completely disagree.  I think your analogy is completely wrong.  How can power be pressure times flow when the pressure sets the flow?  That is like saying A=A*B - it only makes sense when there is no water (A=0)!  Power is flow quantity.  Voltage is quantity of water in a cross-section, current is the driving force behind the water. That way flow quantity = area * force - or P=VI

Comment: Power _is_ pressure times flow. In the metric system, pressure is in Pa (N/m^2, kg/m*s^2), flow is in m^3/s, power is in J (N*m/s, kg*m/s^2). "How can power be pressure times flow when the pressure sets the flow?" First, you're ignoring the resistance [friction, in the fluid model], Second, it'd be more like saying A = B*B, and power is indeed proportional to voltage squared given a constant resistance.

Comment: I think what we have here is some confusion between meaning of terms.  I think we may be confusing pressure as being either the overall barometric pressure of a closed system, or the incoming pressure of water entering the system.  Both are different things.

Comment: @Majenko, I hope that if you still have disagreements you manage to resolve them in chat and work them out. On that note, there is actually a direct physical analog between water systems and electrical system. In my systems dynamics class we were required to know how to build a mechanical, fluid, thermal and electrical systems that had the same transfer functions. There are direct analogs and I have heard many people use the wrong ones. If someone has a strong sense of fluid flow or electrical flow and knows the analogs they can understand both systems by understanding one.

Comment: @Majenko, I have worked with a water system at my job, we have electronic flow sensors and such. There are direct analogs. To measure flow we have a diaphragm that has feeds to each side from the pipe. In the pipe we place a constrained section of pipe(resistor) and we measure how much the diaphragm flexes due to a pressure(voltage) differential.   I have heard poor analogies with water that cause coworkers I have that understand electrical systems misunderstand the water system. People can be a bit harsh, but remember, we are all still learning.

Comment: @Majenko, if your analogy operates in a functional way with parameters mismatched you will still be able to teach with it, but people will apply your analogy as how it actually works in the water system due to the fact that they remember your analogy and may not remember that you were intending it only as an analogy and not a statement of function. Thank you for taking the time and helping others.

Comment: I would happily sort these disagreements out in chat, but do you ever see Olin in chat?  No.  Anyway, I agree that yes, there may be "better" analogies than this one, but just because it isn't the same analogy as Olin's doesn't make it "wrong".  Of course, putting my variables in Olin's analogy won't work.  Neither will putting Olin's variables into my analogy.  The two analogies are different.  There is no such thing as a "perfect" analogy.  yes, some analogies may correlate more variables than another, but that doesn't immediately make all other analogies wrong.

Comment: An analogy, by definition, can never be 100% right - unless you are using something as an analogy to itself - when it ceases to be an analogy.  There is no direct physical link between water in a pipe and electricity.  There is only a relationship between them as interpreted by a transducer.  Yes, there may be "standard" ways of transducing different values, but it is more than possible to change what the transducer creates.  There is only really analogous relationships between two completely different systems with different physical rules and properties that can not be 100% mapped.

Comment: After all, fluid dynamics and Ohms law are not the same.  So yes, please remember that *this is an analogy.  It is not meant to represent a true physical relationship between two disparate systems.  It is merely to illustrate a possible way of looking at how electricity works in a narrative way.  It is not correct, but then neither is any analogy.  There may be better ones, there may be worse ones, but they are different ones and should not be used as a comparison to say that any analogy is wrong per se.  If an analogy stands up within itself then it is correct.  Correctness has no reference*

Comment: *to any other analogy or system - it is purely insular.*  Thank you.

Comment: There is an equation in an analogy just like in a real system. And one of these matches the actual equation and one of these doesn't, is how it seems to me.